# Type Option[java.sql.Timestamp] cannot be used as a default value

Tags: scala, sangria

Trying to get a derived input object from a case class.

```
val UserInputType = deriveInputObjectType[UserRow]()
case class UserRow(id: Int, name: String, lastModifiedTime: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None)
```

but getting this following error

```
Type Option[java.sql.Timestamp] cannot be used as a default value. Please consider defining an implicit instance of `ToInput` for it.
```

I have also defined the type for the timestamp:

```
  case object DateTimeCoerceViolation extends Violation {
    override def errorMessage: String = "Error during parsing DateTime"
  }

  def parseTime(s: String) = Try(Timestamp.valueOf(s)) match {
    case Success(date) ⇒ Right(date)
    case Failure(_) ⇒ Left(DateTimeCoerceViolation)
  }

  implicit val TimestampType = ScalarType[Timestamp](
    "Timestamp",
    coerceOutput = (ts, _) => ts.getTime,
    coerceInput = {
      case StringValue(ts, _, _, _,_) => parseTime(ts)
      case _ => Left(DateTimeCoerceViolation)
    },
    coerceUserInput = {
      case s: String => parseTime(s)
      case _ => Left(DateTimeCoerceViolation)
    }
  )
```

How can solve this ?

Comment: It's very difficult to reproduce the issue. Can you please share more details.

Comment: Scala is not the one throwing the error. sangria is.
https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/issues/224

Comment: For everybody's benefit, seems like there is some complexity in achieving this in sangria. if you have a case class like  ```case class A(id: Int, name: String, lastModifiedTime: Option[Timestamp] = None)```, you will have to remove the ```= None``` and handle the default input of time outside of the case class.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says - **Please consider defining an implicit instance of `ToInput` for it**, you have to provide `ToInput` for `Timestamp` implicitly. Because, without it, sangria will not be able to serialize raw data to `Timestamp`.

```
  implicit val toInput = new ToInput[Option[java.sql.Timestamp], Json] {
    override def toInput(value: Option[Timestamp]): (Json, InputUnmarshaller[Json]) = value match {
      case Some(time) => (Json.fromString(time.toString), sangria.marshalling.circe.CirceInputUnmarshaller)
      case None => (Json.Null, sangria.marshalling.circe.CirceInputUnmarshaller)
    }
  }
```

On the other hand, if are using play-json library, you don't have to explicitly define and use `toInput`.

For example, in `play json`, you can define implicit format for `TimeStamp`.

```
implicit val timeStampFormat: Format = ???
```

Above format will be implicitly used by sangria Json-Marshaller for serializing `Json` to `Timestamp`.

Comment: This solves the problem I am having to set the default value for type Option[T]